# Add class to body in CMS page (with layout update xml from admin panel)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, cms

I'm trying to add a class to body (cms-page-aboutus) via layout XML update inside Magento 2 admin panel.

I know that CMS pages already add a body I could use to target my page, but I need to target multiple CMS pages for several languages at once (cms-about-us, cms-acerca-de, cms-a-propos).

I don't want to duplicate CSS, therefore a common class would be best.

I have tried the following:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="body-class" />
</body>
```

But it fails to save in admin panel:

```
Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'body': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 2
```

Since it seems that only "update" keyword is allowed, I tried using it to add a new handle:

```
<update handle="cms_page_aboutus"/>
```

and then created the file:

```
app/design/<>/<>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_aboutus.xml
```

with the body update within, but it does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: Why you need to add specific class in body, in CMS page you can find already one specific class. i.e: cms-aboutus

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to layout in **Design >  Layout Update XML** of cms page:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="body-class-aaa" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can target body in any layout xml and thus not in admin too as body is above the root element.

It seems to be set in this file `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $htmlAttributes ?>>
    <head <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $headAttributes ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $requireJs ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $headContent ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $headAdditional ?>
    </head>
    <body class="preload" data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $loaderIcon; ?>"}}' <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $bodyAttributes ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $layoutContent ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you overwrite that in your theme you can set a class as shown above.
As you can see there are `$bodyAttributes` too that might enable you to set a class. But I couldn't figure out yet if and how we could set those attributes.